# AVAudioPlayer does not play when app goes to background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, avaudioplayer

I am trying out the `AVFoundationFramework`.

Presently I am able to run the `AVAudioPlayer` in the foreground.
When the app goes to the background, the `AVAudioPlayer` does not continue to play.

The exact steps of implementation are:

1. **Adding Background Tasks to the .plist**

   [image]
2. **Setting up `AVAudioPlayer`**

   ```
   self.objAVAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:mp3Data error:&error];
   self.objAVAudioPlayer.delegate = self;
   ```
3. **Setting up `AVAudioSession`**

   ```
   if([self.objAVAudioPlayer prepareToPlay])
   {
       AVAudioSession *objAVAudioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
       [objAVAudioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
       [objAVAudioSession setActive:YES
                                        error:nil];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
       [self.objAVAudioPlayer play];
   }
   ```

When the app is resumed, it starts from the exact same place where it resigned.

The base SDK is `iOS 7.0`.

Any idea as to what I am missing? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you have in your `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`?

Comment: haven't implemented any code in `applicationDidEnterBackground`

Comment: Do you have the inter-app audio entitlement enabled with your app id?

Comment: you have to wrap it in a background task

Comment: So I have to explicitly put it in another thread or handle it in `applicationDidEnterBackground `

Comment: @akashg: Am testing it in simulator. I also used a developer profile to test it in device. Same results!!

Answer (score 1):

For playing audio in background mode you should set up `AVAudioSession` and add this code

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask]; //Tell the system that we are done with the tasks
    backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Set the task to be invalid
 }];
```

into your `AppDelegate.m` class in method

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    //Some code
}
```

Comment: A small update - the code I shared seems to work fine in `iOS` devices. Was only a problem in simulator.